# What is the best way to model the interior of a vehicle as accurate as possible and what source should I use?

Tags: modeling

so I want to model a bus a bus in blender and I already know how to model the exterior with blueprints however with the interior I'm not sure where to start since it is so complex and I want to model things such as the dashboard, steering wheel, seats, door, engine etc. There is no blueprint available for interior modelling so therefore Iam wondering what is the solution to model the interior of a real life vehicle with accuracy. Also I don't have photographs because they may have distortion and change the way how the object looks.

here is what the bus looks like[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to model the inside accurately is to find a reference image of each individual part of that particular bus or any other bus. This way you will have a good reference that isn't warped in any way. You would then model that part and can use it for your bus. The advantage of modeling the part as a separate object means that you can then use that part in other scenes as well.

For example here is a steering wheel reference from a VW Bus:

[image]